# wnd[1] not found with .findById()

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I'm new to SAP scripting. Someone told me it is possible to automatize my work with VBA, so I looked into it. I looked on the internet how to connect, it works fine. I use the recorder to know what code to write. Everything works very well until the last line of this code:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCAUFVD-AUFNR").Text = "000000000" 'write service order number
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0                              'Confirm (enter)
session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[9]/menu[2]/menu[4]").Select 'execute a function to close the order
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press 'A popup appears (always) with "No" in autoselect. I want to click on "Yes"
```

.findById("wnd[1]") should allow me to use the confirmation popup window, but it always returns Error 619, Control not found. I have no idea why, since this line was written by the recorder. I explored for many hours the Internet and I can't find the answer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I needed to ask to have the resolution idea...

The was I set up my connection was that `session` was actually the `SAP session .ActiveWindow()`, therefore only `wnd[0]`. It couldn't find `wnd[1]`. I execute the `findById()` from the `SAP session` and it works.

```
If Not IsObject(SAPGuiApp) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set SAPGuiApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = SAPGuiApp.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(SAP_session) Then
   Set SAP_session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
Set session = SAP_session.ActiveWindow()
session.findById("wnd[1]") 'Bad. session is only wnd[0]
SAP_session.findById("wnd[1]") 'Good it can find wnd[0] and wnd[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If session.Children.Count > 1 Then
...
end if

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).